# Can html attributes (other than class) have more than one value assigned to them?

Tags: html, attributes, informatica, specifications, has-many

*Apart from the class attribute that can have many values*,
I'm wondering if there are other attributes in html where I could do the same, add multiple attributes separated by spaces?

If so, could you leave a link to where you got that info from?

I read w3 specifications but I couldn't find an answer for this particular question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically *every* attribute with a value has exactly one value... a string.  What that string is allowed to contain depends on what the attribute is and what it does with that information.  For example, `data-` attributes can also contain space characters.  Is there some underlying problem you're trying to solve which led to this question?

Comment: I'm working on a study guide for myself, which I want to complete as much as possible when it comes to concepts and rules of html. Planning to do the same with css and js. Your answer really helps me out, really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

you can create your **custom attributes**, they should start with **data-**  here is an example

```html
<div data-myCustomAttribute="abc def 123 orWhatEverYouWant"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the data- attribute. I'm on the first steps when it comes to web dev , I'll check out this new info.